# Android statusbar extending into toolbar when using coordinator layout with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have an activity that is setup to show a different fragment based on the user's selection in a navigation drawer using the code and layout resources below. The prime fragment which is the first fragment that is loaded when the activity starts. In the prime fragment the toolbar is displayed perfectly well and it is both collapsible and expandable as intended. But when i switch to another fragment i experience two different problems:

1. Status bar extends into toolbar.
2. If the expanded toolbar shown in the prime fragment is collapsed before switching to another fragment, The hamburger icon and the overflow menu buttons no longer appear.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private int activeNavItemId;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Resources resources;
private boolean appBarExpanded;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //The application initially starts with the news fragment which has the       appbar expanded.
    appBarExpanded = true;
    activeNavItemId = -1;
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_layout);
    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)    findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_layout);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    resources = getResources();
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    MenuItem primeMenuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.prime);
    primeMenuItem.setChecked(true);
    onNavigationItemSelected(primeMenuItem);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.timeline, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(settingsIntent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //By default the app bar is not expandable
    boolean expandable = false;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    if (activeNavItemId != -1) {
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(activeNavItemId).setEnabled(true);
    }

    int title = -1;



 if (id == R.id.prime) {
        //Make the app bar expandable when on in the news fragment.
        expandable = true;
        fragmentClass = FragmentPrime.class;
        title = R.string.prime;
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_1) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentHypo.class;
        title = R.string.hypo;
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_2) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentDypo.class;
        title = R.string.dypo;
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_3) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentOz.class;
        title = R.string.oz;
    } else if (id == R.id.frag_4) {
        fragmentClass = FragmentBumbleBee.class;
        title = R.string.bumble_bee;
    }

    try {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
        activeNavItemId = id;
        item.setEnabled(false);
        setAppBarExpandable(expandable);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(resources.getString(title));
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void setAppBarExpandable(boolean expandable) {
    if (expandable && !appBarExpanded) {
        appBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
        toolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(false);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_expand_height);
    } else if (!expandable && appBarExpanded) {
        appBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
        toolbar.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.toolbar_height);
//            collapsingToolbarLayout.invalidate();
    }
    appBarExpanded = expandable;
}
```

}

------------------ activity_main.xml ------------------

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

------------------ app_bar_main.xml ------------------

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="top"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="ParallaxTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <!--<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>-->
</style>

<style name="ParallaxTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/ParallaxTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

Comment: what version of device you are testing the above code?

Comment: Android version 5.1.1

Comment: can you do me a favor. kindly post your style xml and screenshot of what you got?

Comment: Found the source of the errors. It was being caused by the fitsSystemWindow functions i was calling in the setAppBarExpanded function. Everything was ok after removing them.

Comment: fine... happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest activity
put this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".circle.Group_Info"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.DesignDemo"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        />
```

In your style Add these if you are using Appbarlayout:

```
    <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```